# Generalization of Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, newton-series

I noticed the similarity between Taylor series and Newton series:
$$\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{D^nf(0)}{n!} x^n $$

$$\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{\Delta^nf(0)}{n!} x^{\underline{n}} $$
where $Df = df/dx$, $\Delta f(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$, $x^\underline{n} = x(x-1)\ldots(x-n+1)$.

The natural question that comes to mind is that we can generalize that for a more general linear operator $A$ and a family of functions $\{ p_n \}_{n\geq 0}$ which satisfies properties

$$  p_0 (x) = 1 $$
$$ p_n(0)= 0, \ n \geq 1$$
$$ A p_n = n p_{n-1} $$
$$ A1 = 0$$

So we will have the series

$$\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{A^nf(0)}{n!} p_n (x) $$

Has it been studied already?
Which conditions should satisfy $A$, $\{ p_n \}_{n\geq 0}$ so the series converges to $f$? What are the other examples of such series?

Comment: Series of Binomial type can be written as series by means of a delta operator.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_type
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_operator

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes Okay, thanks. I see that $p_n (x+y)$ is expanded to $\sum \binom{n}{k} p_k(x) p_{n-k}(y)$. But why does sequence $p_n$ have to be polynomial?

Comment: And why $A$ have to be shift equivariant? What will break if it's not?